# Magento : How to apply special price for all the products?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

In my store nearly 12,000 products was there. Now i want to apply 10% special price to all my products. Is there any way to implement easily without doing it product by product manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Catalog Price rule and apply to all user groups. I think that will work...

Take a look at http://www.beperpetual.com/2009/04/how-to-setup-customer-pricing-in.html

Comment: Sorry. It's not working.. What may be the problem? Is a have to change any other settings!!

Comment: Sorry again. It's working .. Before i used some condition , bcoz of that it was failed.

Comment: Could you please look on this problem if you like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893342/magento-special-price-not-displaying-in-the-product-page)

Answer (score 1):

there are two way to apply

1.create promotion for product
2.update all product

the price attribute Id is 99

update catalog_product_entity_decimal set value=$price where attribute_Id=99

Comment: Personally I would not just go through each product in the database, but rather do the promotion.