# Magento : Special price not displaying in the product page

Tags: php, magento

I applied the special price rule to all products in the store. Once everything is over the special is displaying in all the pages except the product page(Which displays full product information). I'm using custom theme. Is there any problem with my custom theme?

Comment: Did u used special prices within every product or used catalog price rules? If u used special prices, make sure the special price dates are falling b/w current date. And If u have just changed the template with your custom theme , it wouldn't affect the default magento functionality

Comment: I'm using the Catalog price rules. And i'm not mentioned any date for this. It will applicable for ever.

Comment: Did u added any conditions for that catalog rule? If the special prices are displayed in all pages, what are the changes you made to the product page? Did u applied any custom code for product display page?

Comment: I'm not applied any special condition for the catalog rule. Yes i changed one small code in the catalog.xml in the layout folder. I changed the design from simple to default. After i changed this only price itself displaying.

Comment: Consider revert back to the original catalog.xml and see whether the price is displaying.. Anyway pls post the changes you have done in the catalog.xml

Comment: This is the original catalog.xml file `<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog"><label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label><reference name="product.info"><block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml"><block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra"/></block></reference></PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>` In my custom template instead of **default.phtml** it was **simple.phtml** . When **simple.phtml** normal price itself not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably is a problem with your custom theme.

Try to go back to the default theme, and see if it appears. If it doesn't appear, then is a more complex problem. If it does, then go to your app/design/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/price.phtml and search for the "special price", or paste it here.

Comment: Even i switch over to the default theme also. The same problem, the special price is not displaying!!

Comment: Same issue. Also went back to default theme and no help.

Comment: just a sidenote, if the special price is exact the same you won't see it. just happened with me :)

Answer (score 3):

If you try re-applying your catalog rules and the special prices appear again, make sure your cron job is set up for catalog price rules.